# Git Submodule lost, able to retrieve?

Tags: git

I have a long-standing personal repository for "Resume/", holding my resume contents. I have also had a subdir "Resume/Cover Letter", holding my CV contents that had worked well.
I had created a second git repository inside "Resume/Cover Letter" awhile back, did not think much of it. Now these contents are gone! How can this be though, there is no .gitmodules in my 'Resume' project.

I can see all record  of the Cover Letter repo in the log for Resume/ -

**History Example:**

[image]

But the contents of "Resume/Cover Letter" is empty. Where did these files go? Can they be retrieved? Here is a useful illustration -

**Example**

[image]

**Update**

Doh! See the reference below, for clear warning not to do this -

[image]

Comment: A Git repository cannot hold a Git repository, so when Git encounters a sub-directory that looks like a work-tree with a Git repository in it, Git treats it as a submodule, *even if there is no `.gitmodules` file*. You end up with commits in the superproject that just record the hash ID of whatever commit is currently checked out in the submodule. You're just missing the instructions that a new clone needs, in order to *clone* that submodule.

Comment: There's no standard Git terminology for this, but I have taken to calling them "half assed submodules". They're kind of pernicious.

Comment: @torek agreed! Thank you, your identification of risk and disposition are very clear with articulation, this is appreciated

Comment: As for getting back the files you want ... do you know where there's a good clone of the submodule?

Comment: No there isn’t one! I was surprised on this, part of the learning and growth here for me I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a nested Git repository, your parent repo only records a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

So `git add/git commit/git push` done in the main repository does not add/commit/push files in the nested Git repository at all.
The same command done in the nested repo folder itself would have added/committed/pushed your files.

Comment: Would adding ‘Cover Letter/.git’ to the Resume’s .gitignore fix this?

Comment: @J-Dizzle No, only `Cover Letter/`. But that does not change the fact you would need to go to that folder, define a remote repository, add, commit and push (again, from the `‘Cover Letter` folder) in order to have your changes saved.